# How to use group by for multiple columns with count?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have file called `tags(UserId,MovieId,Tag)` as input for algorithm and convert it into table by registerTempTable .
`val orderedId = sqlContext.sql("SELECT MovieId AS Id,Tag FROM tag ORDER BY MovieId")`
this query give me file consists of Id,tag as input for second step 
 `val eachTagCount =orderedId.groupBy(" Id,Tag").count()`
but error appear

```
case class DataClass( MovieId:Int,UserId: Int, Tag: String)
// Create an RDD of DataClass objects and register it as a table.
val Data = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/tagupdate").map(_.split(",")).map(p => DataClass(p(0).trim.toInt, p(1).trim.toInt, p(2).trim)).toDF()
Data.registerTempTable("tag")
val orderedId = sqlContext.sql("SELECT MovieId AS Id,Tag FROM tag ORDER BY MovieId")
orderedId.rdd
  .map(_.toSeq.map(_+"").reduce(_+","+_))
  .saveAsTextFile("/usr/local/spark/dataset/algorithm3/output")
  val eachTagCount =orderedId.groupBy(" Id,Tag").count()
eachTagCount.rdd
 .map(_.toSeq.map(_+"").reduce(_+","+_))
 .saveAsTextFile("/usr/local/spark/dataset/algorithm3/output2")
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name " Id,Tag" among (Id, Tag);
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:152)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
```

how to solve this error?

Comment: I think you are using groupBy wrong. Usually groupBy would be something like this groupBy(_.id) for example or so on. The way you put " Id,Tag" seems wrong syntax. This tutorial shows you how to do groupBy correctly: http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-8-beginner-tutorial-using-scala-collection-functions/scala-groupby-example/

Comment: This query is one of steps in algorithm written in paper(sciencedirect)

Comment: Can you link this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this 
val eachTagCount =orderedId.groupBy("Id","Tag").count().
You are using single string for multiple columns.

Comment: when changing  val eachTagCount =orderedId.groupBy("Id","Tag").count().same error appear

Comment: It is working for me , can you please share the error you getting after doing the above command .  val eachTagCount =orderedId.groupBy("Id","Tag").count()  output is this i am getting .
eachTagCount: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Id: int, Tag: string ... 1 more field]

Comment: I wrote it with space this reason of error .thanks alot